# My batch file exits upon reaching the nested IF statement

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I just tried to code a simple batch which will help me copy some files with some user-slected options. This batch file exits as soon as it reaches the big if statement

```
Rem @echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a verifier="true to ok: "
:begin
echo Welcome to install!
echo Y - Install
echo N - Remove
choice /m "Select Y/N : "
if "!errorlevel!"=="1" (

 echo Installation:
 echo Y - Default
 echo N - Custom
 choice /m "Select Y/N : "

 if "!errorlevel!"=="2" (

  echo Custom selected 
  goto custom

 ) else (

  xcopy %cd% C:\FPC\
  if "%verifier%"=="true" (

   echo Install OK!

  ) else (

  echo Installation goes wrong!

  )

 )

 echo
 echo Y - Run now
 echo N - Don't run
 choice /m "Select Y/N :"
 if "!errorlevel!"=="1" (

  echo Run
  start start.cmd

 ) else (

  echo Don't run

 )

 goto theend

) else (

 echo Removal
 goto remove

)
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
goto theend
:remove
echo delete something
goto theend
:custom
echo run another batch file
goto theend

:theend
echo the end
pause
```

The batch exits immediately after I typed the (Y/N) choice.
I guess the problem comes from the big if, but I can't find where is wrong or what I'm missing here. 
Thank you for your help! Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Run it from the command line (not by double clicking in Explorer), then you can at least read any error messages that would bomb the script out. Also, the script won't be happy if your labels that you try to GOTO don't exist.

Comment: also, what is this supposed to do ? `set /a verifier=true`?

Comment: Also debug batch scripts by leaving `echo` on e.g. `REM @echo off` and looking at screen output.

Comment: You seem to have non-matching ( and ) brackets in a number of places, and an ELSE that does not have an IF before it.

Comment: Note: in batch scripts you don't have Booleans, only strings and unsigned 32-bit integers, so `set /a verifier=true` will always set `verifier` to `0`. You can do `set verifier=true` and test with `if "%verifier%"=="true"` and `if not "%verifier%"=="true"`

Comment: @michaelharvey Please tell me where I have the non-matching "(" and ")" and the wrong ELSE

Comment: You can count them.

Comment: Have you run the script like I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of Choice is somewhat... mangled.
And your Nested If's are an Unnecesary Complication - Your Making things Harder on yourself than necessary.

```
Syntax should be:
CHOICE /N /C:ir /M "[I]nstall [R]emove"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO Remove
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO Install

:Install
CHOICE /N /C:dc /M "[D]efault [C]ustom"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO Custom
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO Default

:Default
xcopy %cd% C:\FPC\ || GOTO Install_Error
CHOICE /N /C:re /M "[R]un [E]xit"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO Run
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO theend

:Remove
::: options /actions

:Custom
::: options /actions

:Run
::: options /actions

:Install_Error
::: options /actions

:theend
::: options /actions
```

Note: **||** At the end of xcopy Does the following Command when the command preceding **||** returns an Errorlevel

Using choice like this saves alot of headaches and makes your code more readable and easier to maintain.

If you want to save yourself some typing, heres a way to make it simpler.

At the start of your batch:

```
Set "ask=CHOICE /N /C:"
Set "doIF=IF ERRORLEVEL =="
```

And then whenever you need choice:

```
%ask%ir /M "[I]nstall [R]emove"
%doIF%2 GOTO Remove
%doIF%1 GOTO Install
```

Comment: Choice is useful as more than just a means of input. It's a forced script break that ensures only the desired actions occur - Worth using heavily for that alone in any program where the user makes numerous choices.

The timeout / default Switch in particular is very useful If your making a program that you want to be Semi Autonomous - Set the defaults up to run it through the default commands, and still have the option to skip or adjust actions depending on output.